# Best practice to client-server communication on Android, when and how

Tags: android, json, performance, sqlite, client-server

I am implementing the client-server communication for an app on android. I have some high-level questions before I start to code.  *Apologize if the question turns out vague or confusing. I am really new to this (2 days of Google-ing is all I have), and I haven't coded anything because this design issue I am asking.*

**Background:** Our android app records users activities. These activities are, for example, the user bookmarks an article. Eventually we want to synchronize these activities with server's database. However this sync is not time-critical, meaning it is not necessary that we send the activity to the server every time there is a new activity.

**Current Design:** Every time there is an activity, we get the activities and put it in a Java object, mark as "notSync", then make an update call to the database (SQLite) on the mobile.  Every 5 minutes or so we make a call into the database, pull the nonSync items into an array of objects, convert it to JSON, and send it to the server.

**Question 1:** It seems rather inefficient to put an object into database, then every a few minutes pull it out from database as an array of objects, then convert to JSON.  Would that be a better design, if we just append all the activities to an array of objects, then convert to JSON directly from that array and clear that array? My dilemma is that, If we implement the latter, there might potentially be a huge array floating around in phone's memory. How do we choose what is the best to implement?

**Question 2** When sync mobile SQLite with server MySQL, is our design (using java to pull the rows out as an array of objects, then converting it to JSON) a reasonable practice?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing to keep in mind is where the bottlenecks really are.  In my experience communicating with a MySQL server, the connection takes by far the longest, followed by uploading/downloading data, followed by anything I did on the phone.  So even without knowing exactly what you're going to be recording, I think it's a safe bet that using SQLite and creating objects will not have a big time impact compared to your network activity.

I would run some basic tests to measure how long various operations take, but to answer your questions:

1. If you clear the array properly, you won't have to worry about it growing too big and, if your array ever did get that big, you probably have other things to worry about (uploading many MBs of data).  However, if your user does something for 4 minutes, then quits the app or something, they'll lose their data.  Storing it in the DB is safer.
2. JSON seems to be the best way to send your data, it's quite efficient for that, and as I said above, I don't thing the SQLite/object creation time will be too great.

Comment: Those are some helpful insights. Thanks.